# Ubuntu 18.04 randomly logs out to black screen / second screen issue

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

This issue appeared outta nowhere. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Latitude 5591, and I noticed this after I disconnected my second monitor from my PC.

My PC started randomly shutting down (logging off, I get a black screen and I have to press the power button for it to run again, and it prompts me for my password) after every 30 seconds or less, the resolution went a bit wild and if I go to Displays inside Settings it says that it "Can't get screen information".
In addition every time I plug in the external display everything works on that external screen but not on the one on my laptop.

I tried most of the solutions that I could find online but nothing really helped.

Thanks for the help :)

```
xrandr (without the external display because I'm currently at home):
```

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93    48.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

If you want that I run any other commands to get logs or helpful information please let me know.

Comment: I have the same laptop with the same issue. I am using a WD15 docking station

Comment: I also want to point out that you submitted this issue exactly one month after the package manager got the new bios-version package. What version of the bios are you running `sudo dmidecode -s bios-versoin`